# How to center a Row containing wrapped text within a Column

Tags: flutter

I am having difficulty figuring how to get a `Row`, which contains wrapped text, to appear centered in a `Column`.

The issue seems to be that `Flexible` (or `Expanded` for that matter) causes the `Text` widget to consume the entire remaining horizontal space in the `Row`. This seems fine for text layout purposes, i.e., determining the needed height for the text. However, it also seems to me that is should be possible that once the text has been laid out, the bounds of its widget can be "shrunk" to require only the minimum width necessary. (Notice the difference of width/space within the red bounding box in the images below.)

Is it possible to achieve this in Flutter? What am I overlooking?

I have searched high and low on SO and haven't found this specific question.

The closest related *might* be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74114363/3558355) but it's difficult to be certain the way that question was asked. (And it did not receive any answers.)

### What I am seeing

[image: undesired appearance]

### What I would like to see

[image: desired appearance]

### What I have tried

- Several permutations of `Flexible` and `Expanded`, around the `Text`, `Row`, and `Column` in various combinations
- Several different values for `fit` and `flex` (with `Flexible`)
- `IntrinsicWidth` parent on `Column`
- `softWrap`

### Code

(Based on the "Counter" sample from [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev).)

```dart
// Copyright (c) 2019, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
// for details. All rights reserved. Use of this source code is governed by a
// BSD-style license that can be found in the LICENSE file.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent),
        ),
        width: 300,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                const Text(
                  '\u{1F603}',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 24.0,
                  ),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.red),
                    ),                    
                    child: const Text(
                      'Some text that ends up taking_two_lines',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welp, as I was typing up this question, I discovered the solution, so I may as well write it up for others.

The trick was to use the [`textWidthBasis`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text/textWidthBasis.html) argument of `Text` and set it to [`TextWidthBasis.longestLine`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextWidthBasis.html).

Answer (score 0):

**If you has parent widget set yours to center too**

> In my case i set My Colum(mainAlignment to center and it is work for me)

```
Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent),
        ),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        width: 300,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                const Text(
                  '\u{1F603}',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 24.0,
                  ),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.red),
                    ),
                    child: const Text(
                      'Some text that ends up taking_two_lines',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its help to you I have try same as your expected design

Your Widget:

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    actions: [
      const Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: Text(
            'Flutter',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 18.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
  body: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          const SizedBox(
            width: 50,
          ),
          const Text(
            '\u{1F603}',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 24.0,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: const Text(
              'Some text that ends up taking_two_lines',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 18.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Result Screen-> [image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you please elaborate on what specific change you made and what it does / why it works?

Comment: I my answer I have used [Column](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html), [Row](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html) and [Expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) Widgets I have used [Alignments](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html) like `spacebetween` as well as [Layouts](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout) in that, I am try to design your expected design